# Handling X-request-id request header from Here Maps Routing Javascript API

Tags: here-api

Migrating Here maps RoutingAPI from 7 to V8. Need to set X-Request-Id in request header and read the same from response.

**Old implementation in version 7**: sending "requestId" as query param and reading the value from "response.metaInfo.requestId" node coming in response

```
router.calculateRoute(
    {
        ...
        "requestId": "Route_1"
    },
    CallBackFn,
    function (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
);
```

**Trying to set as below in Version V8:**

```
_platform = new H.service.Platform({
      apikey: _appkey,
    });
router = _platform.getRoutingService(null, 8);
router.i = {"X-Request-ID": "Route_1"}
```

From the above code, able to set request header. But not able to read from response header from callback function

Answer (score 0):

routing v7: requestId
routing v8: Use the header X-Request-ID

```
X-Request-ID
```

You can tag your requests with a request identifier using the non-standard HTTP header X-Request-Id. The service will forward this value to the response, be it a success or a failure. If no value is provided, a UUID will be generated on the incoming request and this value will be attached to the response as the X-Request-Id. While you can use any string as the request identifier, we recommend using a UUID to uniquely identify your requests or group of requests.

migration guide : https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/migration_guide/index.html

v8 guide : https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/trace-request.html